# Split access database or recommend other software

Tags: database

I have a ms access database that I use in our business and I want to split it, give different users different applications/modules that connect to the back-end.   We have 7 computer users and all will get one or more "applications" to use.   There would probably only be 1-3 users accessing the file at any given time.

The software we use to run our business is in the cloud and has nothing to do with ms access - access is used as an adjunct - we get along fine as-is but we will perform better if I can get this accomplished

We aren't using a server at our business.   I think I want/need the backend hosted in the cloud so I can get to it from anywhere.

I like access but if I need to learn other software, I will.   Any advise is appreciated.   Thanks